# Using SQLAdapter and SQLCommandBuilder without a Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql, .net, data-synchronization

I'm exploring the use of `SqlCommandBuilder` alongside `Adapter.Update()` to synchronize a DataGridView with an SQL Database table.

I want to auto-generate SQL Update statements using `SqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()`, however, it fails with
"`Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information`". This makes sense, because my table **doesn't have a primary key**.

I cannot set the primary key on the source table, but I do have an identity column.
I'd like to specify to the command builder which column to use as the primary key. There is such a feature on the DataTable class, but it seems to have no effect on the `SqlCommandBuilder`.

I tried the following:

```
// Add Primary Key to help command builder identify unique rows
Table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Table.Columns["ComponentID"] };
```

But it seems that this information does not propagate to the `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlCommandBuilder` because I still get the error.

Here's the order I've tried:

```
// get data
Adapter.Fill(Table);

// specify primary key column
Table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Table.Columns["ComponentID"] };

cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(Adapter);

cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand() // <-- Error here
```

Are there any solutions here at all, or do I have to specify the update and insert statements?

Comment: `I cannot set the primary key on the source table, but I do have an identity column.` why? Why does the table have no primary key while it has an IDENTITY column? That's the real question. This is not a `that's how it is`, a missing primary is a *major* issue. In any case, SqlCommandBuilder was created to generate queries for DataTables, and those *require* primary keys. The DbDataAdapter isn't configured by the tables it fills, so setting a PK on the table won't affect the adapter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As mentioned in my question, I cannot modify the table. It is regretable, but that is often a constraint here so discussing it further is irrelevant. Thank you for clarifying that bit about the DbDataAdapter  though.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to just write your own update command then, instead of using the builder, no?

Comment: @CetinBasoz Not very scalable if I have many different tables to pull from. I could write my own SqlCommandBuilder class, and I may if there isn't a better option.

Comment: @ArmandBernard in that case SqlCommandBuilder is inappropriate. `that is often a constraint here` on the contrary, that's a strong indicator that something is wrong, and either the solution is wrong or even that the wrong problem is being solved. Why use a DbDataAdapter *at all*? This class went out of fashion 10 years ago as people abandoned typed datasets for ORMs and plain classes. If you want to generate queries for a table, why not use an ORM? That's what it's for. It will also be a LOT faster - what you try here will have to generate queries every time its used. ORMs cache queries

Comment: What is the *real* problem you want to solve? Do you really want to work with datasets and use a data adapter to load the data? Or was this an attempt to generate an UPDATE from a SELECT? Or perhaps, generate Select and Update queries for a table? (Which brings us back to the out-of-the-box tool for this, EF Core)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to provide the user with an easy way to edit a database table's content without using SSMS or similar. This would come in the form of a datagridview with modifiable cells. Then, I want to synchronise those changes back up to the database.
I've heard that is what the SQLAdapater class is for. If you know of any alternatives, do let me know.
What CANNOT change is how the data is stored. I.e. in SQL form in that table, so eventually it will come back to having to update that table one way or another.

Comment: No, the DbDataAdapter classes were used to load DataSet and DataTables that may have relations between them identified by FKs. They could generate Update and Delete queries as well, to allow editing eg in datagrids, but to do that you *must* have a PK in the table. You need PKs in tables even if you write raw queries, because that's the thing that identifies a row. It's easy to find the PK of a table. If you have a bunch of unique indexes though, which one is the actual key?  Having a unique indexed IDENTITY without making it a PK makes little sense, and definitely harms overall performance.

Comment: The DbDataAdapter classes retrieve schema information from the database to create their queries. You can retrieve such information too, using eg [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server. You can also use the [GetSchemaTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatareader.getschematable?view=net-5.0#System_Data_IDataReader_GetSchemaTable) of a DataReader to receive metadata about a query

Comment: @ArmandBernard, why wouldn't it be scalable? You are typing cmdBuilder ... and then cmdBuildet.GetUpdateCommand(); No? Instead you would simply create your own method, that returns back an update command based on the PK you pass it to. I have been doing that maybe more than 20 years and it works nicely (before .Net was available, in another language of course). And also there are types of update commands such as that base the update only on PK or all columns.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So you are saying that primary keys provide unique values throughout the database? That is indeed useful to prevent people accidentally joining two unrelated tables. However, an identity column is enough to identify rows within a table, and refer to them from outside that table as long as you know which table you are referring to. Not good enough for DbDataAdapter and other automated methods though. Still, useful information.
I'll remember that if I ever get the opportunity to use them in a new database.
Doesn't apply here though.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Like I said, I can write my own SQL query generator, based on provided table, keys etc. I just wanted to find out if it was necessary. No use duplicating work.
I'll go write it later, unless you'd like to submit your code as an answer.

Comment: I don't have some code ready. I would do a .Fill(dataTable) and send that table to "my builder" method, along the name of the key column names as params. That method could use that dataTable to find out the column names and types to generate the update command like : Update myTable set CustomerId = @ p1, companyName = @ p2, ... where keyColumn = @ pN. And then set the parameters collection, based on data types. (I have the code in another language and it is working)

Comment: @CetinBasoz That's a smart move! I may use it to simplify my solution I have provided below rather than having to provide those values manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as pointed out by @PanagiotisKanavos, the `SqlCommandBuilder` does not support tables without primary keys, even if you set it in the `DataTable` object.

Therefore, I had no choice but write my own Command Builder.

To use it, you need to provide:

- The SqlConnection to use
- The Database (if not provided in the connection)
- The SQLAdapter, with the Select Command already set (there's a constructor for that)

How you use it:

```
string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [dbCache].[dbo].[Component] ORDER BY [ComponentType] DESC";

// Initialize the SqlDataAdapter object by specifying a Select command 
// that retrieves data from the table.
Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, Connection)
{
    FillLoadOption = LoadOption.PreserveChanges,
    MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
};

// build all sql commands
Adapter = SQLCommandBuilder.BuildAll(Adapter, Connection);
```

Next, the full class code:

```
public static class SQLCommandBuilder
{
    public enum CommandType
    {
        Update = 0,
        Insert = 1,
        Delete = 2
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Build and add the insert, update and delete commands to the given SqlAdapter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="adapter"></param>
    /// <param name="connection"></param>
    /// <param name="database"></param>
    /// <param name="idColumns"></param>
    /// <returns>the modified adapter</returns>
    public static SqlDataAdapter BuildAll(
        SqlDataAdapter adapter, SqlConnection connection, string database = null, string[] idColumns = null
        )
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        // fill datatable with select data
        adapter.Fill(data);

        if (database == null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connection.Database))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "Could not determine database from connection object. Please specify it manually"
                    );
            }
            // get database from connection
            database = connection.Database;
        }
        // get table name
        string table = data.TableName;
        // get all column names
        string[] allColumns = data.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Select(col => col.ColumnName).ToArray();
        
        // only get id columns if the user has not manually specified them
        if (idColumns == null)
        {
            // get id columns from the table. This includes any unique or auto-incrementing column
            idColumns = data.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Where(col => col.AutoIncrement || col.Unique)
                .Select(col => col.ColumnName)
                .ToArray();

            // if no id columns found
            if (idColumns.Length == 0)
            {
                // throw an error
                throw new Exception("No ID columns found in the table!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // if the specfified columns don't exist
            if (idColumns.All(id => allColumns.Contains(id, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                // throw an error
                throw new ArgumentException("Provided ID columns do not exist in the table!");
            }
        }
        

        // generate all commands
        adapter.InsertCommand =
            BuildCommand(CommandType.Insert, connection, database, table, allColumns, idColumns);
        adapter.UpdateCommand =
            BuildCommand(CommandType.Update, connection, database, table, allColumns, idColumns);
        adapter.DeleteCommand =
            BuildCommand(CommandType.Delete, connection, database, table, allColumns, idColumns);

        // return the modified adapter
        return adapter;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Build a command of the given type using the provided parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmdtype"></param>
    /// <param name="connection"></param>
    /// <param name="database"></param>
    /// <param name="table"></param>
    /// <param name="allColumns"></param>
    /// <param name="idColumns"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SqlCommand BuildCommand(
        CommandType cmdtype, SqlConnection connection, string database, string table, 
        string[] allColumns, string[] idColumns
        )
    {
        if (allColumns == null || allColumns.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("allColumns", "allColumns cannot be null or empty!");
        }
        if (idColumns == null || idColumns.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("idColumns", "idColumns cannot be null or empty!");
        }

        string strCommand = null;

        switch (cmdtype)
        {
            case CommandType.Insert:

                // get columns to set values for. Id columns not included because they should
                // be set by the table
                string[] insertCols = allColumns.Except(idColumns).ToArray();

                strCommand =
                    "INSERT INTO [" + database + "].[dbo].[" + table + "]\n" +
                    "([" + string.Join("], [", insertCols) + "])\n" +
                    "VALUES (@" + string.Join(", @", insertCols.Select(s => s.Replace(" ", ""))) + ")";
                break;
            case CommandType.Update:
                // compare each id column to a paremeterized variable of the same name prefixed with "old"
                string[] idCompsOld = idColumns
                    .Select(col => "[" + col + "] = @old" + col.Replace(" ", ""))
                    .ToArray();

                // create a setting statement. Don't set id columns, as they should never be modifiable
                string[] setStatement = allColumns.Except(idColumns)
                    .Select(col => "[" + col + "] = @" + col.Replace(" ", ""))
                    .ToArray();

                strCommand =
                    "UPDATE [" + database + "].[dbo].[" + table + "]\n" +
                    "SET " + string.Join(", ", setStatement) + "\n" +
                    "WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", idCompsOld);
                break;
            case CommandType.Delete:
                // compare each id column to a paremeterized variable of the same name
                string[] idComps = idColumns
                    .Select(col => "[" + col + "] = @" + col.Replace(" ", ""))
                    .ToArray();
                strCommand =
                    "DELETE FROM [" + database + "].[dbo].[" + table + "]\n" +
                    "WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", idComps);
                break;
        }

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strCommand, connection);

        // cycle through all columns
        for( int i = 0; i < allColumns.Length; i++)
        {
            string col = allColumns[i];

            // create a parameter for that column
            SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@" + col.Replace(" ", ""),
                SourceColumn = col
            };
            // add the paramter to the command
            command.Parameters.Add(para);

            // in the special case of the update statement, extra parameters are needed for the
            // old values
            if (cmdtype == CommandType.Update)
            {
                // create a parameter for that column
                para = new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@old" + col.Replace(" ", ""),
                    SourceColumn = col,
                    SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
                };
                // add the paramter to the command
                command.Parameters.Add(para);
            }
        }

        return command;
    }
}
```

Using the following code to print the commands:

```
// Display the Update, Insert, and Delete commands that were automatically generated
// by the SQLCommandBuilder.
Console.WriteLine("Update command : ");
Console.WriteLine(Adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Insert command : ");
Console.WriteLine(Adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Delete command : ");
Console.WriteLine(Adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText);
Console.WriteLine();
```

I get:

```
Update command : 
UPDATE [dbCache].[dbo].[Component]
SET [ComponentType] = @ComponentType, [Drawings] = @Drawings, [StatusNo] = @StatusNo
WHERE [ComponentlD] = @oldComponentlD 

Insert command :
INSERT INTO [dbCache].[dbo].[Component]
([ComponentType], [Drawings], [StatusNo])
VALUES (@ComponentType, @Drawings, @StatusNo) 

Delete command :
DELETE FROM [dbCache].[dbo].[Component]
WHERE [ComponentlD] = @ComponentlD
```

I have tested the insert, update and delete statements and they seem to all work!

Comment: It was something like this I meant :)

Comment: @CetinBasoz updated my solution to only practically need the SqlAdapter and SqlConnection from the user. It determines everything else itself as long as the select query is set.

Comment: Great :) BTW adapter already have the connection info in it (at least in SelectCommand).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Is that so? In that case that's one more argument I can remove! I will update this later

Comment: I am not sure but it should have that, check adapter.SelectCommand.Connection. Or something like that should exist. Yes it has that. Just checked.